# Fill div tag with text using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a webpage where I need to fill some text data in div tags using VBA. I know how to fill data in input tags. I have tried it using .value="data" and .innertext="data". But I am not able to achieve the results.
Below is the source code for it.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="RichTextEditorWidget" role="textbox"
aria-describedby="cke_79" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"
aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor5" dojoattachpoint="_editorAttachPoint">
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.innerText="value"

this is working